# Accidentally deleted tmp folder

Tags: tmp

i was trying to run

```
sudo rm -r ./tmp
```

but instead typed

```
sudo rm -r /tmp
```

Will it be fixed by running?

```
sudo mkdir /tmp
```

if i do what permissions should i give it?

ps: i didnt log out of my system yet

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I can't think of a reason why this shouldn't work. On my system, the permissions are set by:

```
sudo chmod 1777 /tmp
```

(drwxrwxrwxt)

Comment: I rebooted my system after deleting the `/tmp` folder and now it is not getting past `lightdm`.

Answer (score 10):

You should run the following commands to restore the tmp folder.

```
sudo -i
# You now have a root prompt and do not need to continue typing sudo
mkdir /tmp
chmod 1777 /tmp
exit
```

Then you sould be all good

Comment: I think that exiting the root prompt after the steps would be worth mentioning.

Answer (score 4):

To add to Alex's answer, you can do both those commands at the same time using the `-m` or `--mode` option for [**mkdir**(1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/mkdir.1posix.html), which specifies the mode for the created directory:

```
-m, --mode=MODE   set file mode (as in chmod), not a=rwx - umask
```

So the command would be:

```
sudo mkdir -m 1777 /tmp
```