# Accidentally moved `/tmp` - replacements won't persist

Tags: filesystem, rm, tmp

I did `sudo mv /tmp /var/lib/apt/lists` not realizing that it would move the whole folder and not just the contents.

I since do (as suggested in [Accidentally deleted tmp folder](https://askubuntu.com/q/178751/229472))

```
sudo mkdir -m 1777 /tmp
```

on startup, but after a while it disappears again.
What can I do? how can I debug this?

It seems that `/tmp` is renamed to `/snapshot.0` (or with a higher index if other snapshots already exist).

Restart does not solve it. But shutting down without a `/tmp` isn't a problem either, on startup a new `/tmp` is there.
However within 4 minutes it is renamed to another snapshot.

### What happens without /tmp:

- no tab completion in bash (sometimes)
- programs such as chromium-browser and system monitor don't start
- apt-get seems to rely on /tmp as well

I currently execute `sudo mv /snapshot.0 /tmp` whenever `/tmp` disappears.

### Experiments:

I start the computer(as we will see `/tmp` is still there apparently it survived restart) and open a terminal where I execute:

```
$ while true; do 
   t=$(date +%H:%M:%S);      #timestamp as hour minute seconds
   date;ls -lt / | head -3;  print out date and most recent folders in /
   ls -l /tmp        > ~/Desktop/ls.tmp.log.${t}; 
   ls -l /snapshot.0 > ~/Desktop/ls.snap.log.${t}; 
   sleep 60; 
done;
```

I do nothing else!
log in terminal:

```
Di 23. Jun 19:44:12 CEST 2020
total 2097264
drwxrwxrwt  18 root root       4096 Jun 23 19:44 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  34 root root       1000 Jun 23 19:42 run
ls: cannot access '/snapshot.0': No such file or directory
Di 23. Jun 19:45:12 CEST 2020
total 2097264
drwxrwxrwt  18 root root       4096 Jun 23 19:44 tmp
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root          0 Jun 23 19:44 sys
ls: cannot access '/snapshot.0': No such file or directory
Di 23. Jun 19:46:12 CEST 2020
total 2097264
drwxrwxrwt  18 root root       4096 Jun 23 19:44 tmp
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root          0 Jun 23 19:44 sys
ls: cannot access '/snapshot.0': No such file or directory
Di 23. Jun 19:47:12 CEST 2020
total 2097264
drwxrwxrwt  18 root root       4096 Jun 23 19:44 tmp
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root          0 Jun 23 19:44 sys
ls: cannot access '/snapshot.0': No such file or directory
Di 23. Jun 19:48:12 CEST 2020
total 2097264
drwxrwxrwt  18 root root       4096 Jun 23 19:44 tmp
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root          0 Jun 23 19:44 sys
ls: cannot access '/snapshot.0': No such file or directory
Di 23. Jun 19:49:13 CEST 2020
total 2097264
drwxrwxrwt  18 root root       4096 Jun 23 19:48 snapshot.0
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root          0 Jun 23 19:44 sys
ls: cannot access '/tmp': No such file or directory
```

So within 5 minutes /tmp has been renamed to /snapshot.0.

there is no difference between ls.tmp.log.19:4[4-8]:12 There is also no difference between `ls.tmp.log.19:48:12` and `ls.snap.log.19:49:13` so it can't be the content of `/tmp`.

### Progress:

While I was hoping for a solution that makes things as they were before(without reinstalling the system) Giorgos Saridakis' [suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/a/1253171/229472) of symlinks <strike>does work</strike> helps a lot. However I still can't start system monitor:

```
$ gnome-system-monitor 
cannot create temporary directory for the root file system: Permission denied
```

despite having all permissions set:

```
$ ls -lt /
total 2097264
drwxrwxrwt   8 root root       4096 Jun 27 15:21 snapshot.0
-rw-r--r--   1 root root          0 Jun 27 15:10 lifesign
...
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root         11 Jun 23 22:12 tmp -> /snapshot.0
```

<strike>I guess I'll have to write a demon after all...</strike>

I wrote a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true;
do
    if [ ! -d "/tmp" ];
    then mv /snapshot.0  /tmp 2>> /home/t/tmp.rename.bg.err;
     date >> /home/t/tmp.rename.bg.log;
    fi;
    sleep 10;
done
```

that is executed with

```
sudo bash tmp.rename.sh &
```

after login. It's not ideal but I don't have to get into writing daemons just yet.

Comment: This might seem silly, but have you tried moving it back with `sudo mv /var/lib/apt/lists /tmp`?

Comment: @tfstwbbnb Yes, I did.

Comment: Was your `/tmp` originally a simple directory or a filesystem ? You can check with `grep /tmp /etc/fstab` and post the result if something is found.

Comment: @ChrisAga I think it was just a directory, I don't remember doing anything special for `/tmp`. 
`grep /tmp /etc/fstab` returns nothing.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you've stumbled on a persistent part of the Kernel, I believe this is not solvable in the proper way.

In the absence of will to reinstall the whole system, why don't you try creating a symbolic (or a hard) link from /snapshot.0 to /tmp:

```
sudo ln -s /snapshot.0 /tmp
```

If that doesn't work, I would make a small daemon to constantly check if /tmp is there and create it, if not found (with lock permissions maybe).

Difficult situation, I sympathize :)

Comment: Hmm, I was really hoping I didn't have to reinstall the system...
Do you think a version upgrade might fix it?
How should I go into the next upgrade, with /tmp deleted or symlinked?

Comment: Maybe a kernel update will fix things, but who can say ? if the links don't work (supposing that maybe a hard link will keep /tmp alive, that's the idea), apart from a system upgrade, a simple daemon will do the job. It's not perfect of course, but you could live with it

Comment: Giorgos, what do you mean by "_a persistent part of the kernel_"? Are you saying this regular rename is a kernel bug? It's certainly not normal behaviour and I can't find it documented as a side-effect anywhere. (The closest I can find is `snapper`, but that's only on a match for `snapshot.0`.) Thanks

Comment: It appears the kernel seeks to locate a given i-node for /tmp and removes the new /tmp created again and again. This would certainly not be a kernel bug, rather a security measure, which probably doesn't have to do with /tmp alone. I am simply interpreting what is observed roaima and making the best guess from that perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the create one after booting and make a new directory of tmp as followed:

`sudo mkdir -m 1777 /tmp`
`chown root:root /tmp`

here -m is called mode of creation of a directory,which Set the file permission bits of the newly-created  directory  to  the  specified mode  value.

After executing the above command, Now run the command below to check the permissions of the directory.

`ls -ld /tmp`

and It should be looking like this

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: The newly created `/tmp` directory has been moved to `snapshot.0` as well...

Comment: does this repeatedly happen ?

Comment: Yes, for example after the log that I added to the question, I created a new `/tmp` dir. It lasted for 50 minutes until it got replaced.

Comment: Do you experience even after transferring the ownership to root? Do you use root as a default user in Kali Linux?

Comment: I'm not using Kali but Ubuntu. My default user is not root. I don't have to transfer ownership  since `sudo mkdir` already sets root as the owner.